# Is there a way to group a dictionary in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Trying to groupby a small dictionary of countries by continents in pandas.  The result should be an index of continents as the index and the number of countries in the first column.

```
 ContinentDict  = {'China':'Asia',
'United States':'North America', 
    'Japan':'Asia',
    'United Kingdom':'Europe', 
    'Russian Federation':'Europe', 
    'Canada':'North America', 
    'Germany':'Europe',  
    'India':'Asia','France':'Europe', 
    'South Korea':'Asia', 
    'Italy':'Europe',  
    'Spain':'Europe',                
    'Iran':'Asia', 
    'Australia':'Australia',
    'Brazil':'South America'}
```

output should look like this

```
Index Country    Column1
Asia               5
United States      2
Europe             6...
```

Doesn't have to be sorted in any order

code so far

```
countries_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ContinentDict,orient='index')
    #columns=['size', 'sum', 'mean', 'std']
    #countries_df = countries_df.rename(columns={0:"sampCol"})
    #countries_df[columns[0]]=np.nan
    #countries_df[columns[1]]=np.nan
    #countries_df[columns[2]]=np.nan
    #countries_df[columns[3]]=np.nan
    #countries_df=countries_df.set_index('A').groupby(0)
    countries_df=countries_df.rename(index={" ":"Countries"})
    
    #countries_df=countries_df.groupby('sampCol')
    #countries_df = countries_df.sum()

   
    #countries_df['size']=countries_df.groupby(['sampCol']).sum()
    
    return countries_df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
countries_df = pd.DataFrame(continentDict.items(), columns=('country', 'continent'))
countries_df.groupby('continent').count()
```

```
               country
continent             
Asia                 5
Australia            1
Europe               6
North America        2
South America        1
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pandas.Series.groupby` with `count`:

```
s = pd.Series(ContinentDict, name="Country")
s.groupby(s).count()
```

Output:

```
Country
Asia             5
Australia        1
Europe           6
North America    2
South America    1
Name: Country, dtype: int64
```